# Read an XML (without DTD/schema) and write the values into db

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, xsd

Objective :
I'm writing a program in C# to read an XML (without DTD/schema) and write the values of each tag into a database(SQL Server).

Approach : 
I'm using an xml parser (XMLReader) to parse the XML.
I'm creating the tables(currently manually but planning to automate it) based on XSD created using xsd.exe.
Based on the tag-name i'm fetching all the attributes and corresponding values and storing it into corresponding tables.

Problem :
Now if any new tag is introduced into the xml being parsed i have to change my code written for parsing and storing.

Is there any other approach i should use or can i use same approach with modifications to achieve the objective.

Comment: Well, even if you automate this, you will have to change your code for parsing and storing as new tags will asumedly introduce new columns on your tables. Unless you have a table that just has fields like path, value in which case you can just stuff each element or node in a separate row, but this would suck. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually there is an application 'A' which sends some data in xml. Appliaction 'B' (QlikView) cannot read directly from xml that's why i have to write a program that reads values from xml and store into database so that our application 'B' can query the database for desired values.

Comment: If you are using slq server you can shred the xml and stick it right into database tables with a stored proc or sql server service broker. See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/XML/87685/ or http://www.olcot.co.uk/sql-blogs/shredding-a-simple-xml-structure-to-a-single-row-flat-table

Comment: It sounds like a better approach, only one problem : what if the input xml file is a duplicate file or any value/set of values are duplicate?

Comment: Also in the store proc we have to explicitly mention the cloumn name for inserting values, which again brings the overhead of changing the sp if a new tag is introduced int the xml.

Comment: Well I guess you have a choice of doing it with a stored proc or creating some sort of mapping where you map the xml elements and attributes to columns in a table then your program reads this mapping file, parses into a dynamic objects like so http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/07/parse-xml-to-dynamic-object-in-c.html and for each object creates an insert into the database. New tags are ignored till you update the mapping file which can of course be an xml file too.